# FTPS failing on LIST command with error;

Tags: linux, ftp, ftps, vsftpd, gnutls

The machine in question is running CentOS 5.7 and vsftpd-2.0.5-21.el5.x86_64.

My client can connect to the server and interact with it normally over standard FTP.  It can also connect via FTPS and authenticate properly, but when my client (Filezilla) attempts a LIST command, it receives the following error;

> GnuTLS error -53: Error in the push function

GnuTLS is fully updated from repo to gnutls-1.4.1-3.el5_4.8.x86_64.

Comment: Do you run firewall? If so - try with no firewall. If it would be hard to try with no firewall - try to allow (and use) unencrypted listing and then encrypted transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a firewall (could be software, on either the server or client, or hardware) somewhere between your client and server. The `LIST` command causes the client to open a second connection to the server (called the "data channel"), which is being blocked. Check your server configuration for `pasv_min_port` and `pasv_max_port`, and make sure that any firewalls between the client and server allow traffic on those and *all* of the ports in between from the client to the server.

The reason plain FTP isn't affected by this is that most firewalls will actually inspect the commands and responses sent between the client and server and determine dynamically which ports to open for the data channel. Because that communication is encrypted when using FTPS, this inspection cannot occur.